# How can i write this expression in C++ using cout?

Tags: c++

how can i write this C expression in c++ using cout ?
   is this a valid statement in C++ too?

```
printf("%c",65+y);
```

Comment: Have you at least tried it? Did the compiler accept it? With extra warnings enabled? Did it produce the expected output?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid magic numbers.  If you want to add to the letter A then use `'A' + y`

Comment: On another note, please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by the integer `65` means the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoded character `'A'` then *use it*.

Comment: That depends on the *type* and *value* of `y`. Not enough here to answer sensibly. Please include a compilable example.

Comment: Also note that while it will work with ASCII, the C++ specification doesn't guarantee that letters are encoded consecutively. There are encodings where the letters have gaps between them, and where this will not work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude; That still depends on the type of `y`, unless of course they meant `65 + 'y'`: and doesn't that oveflow the `char` type if `signed`, even in ASCII?

Comment: Lastly, if you indeed mean `'A' + y`, then remember that the result of that expression is an *`int`*, not a `char`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That's the issue I have: that `int` might not fit into a `char` any more.

Comment: @Bathsheba And that really depends on what `y` is and what its value is (as you mentioned). If the result is supposed to be an ASCII encoded upper-case letter then I hope that the OP have validated the value in `y` to make sure it's valid and the result is within range.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- when passed as an argument through an ellipsis, `char` gets promoted to `int`. So `printf` expects that argument to have type `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
std::cout << char (65 + y);
```

per comment `A` has numerical value of 65 thus `65 + y`. So above is the same as this:

```
std::cout << char ('A' + y);
```

Advice learn about casting in C++.

Comment: The OP should prefer 'A' to 65.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use it the C way as long as you keep `#include <stdio.h>`.

A modern solution would be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   int y = 5;
   std::cout << static_cast<char>(y + 'A') << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To improve the answer, you should probably explain *why* the cast is needed.

Comment: Benchmark this against the old-fashioned way and wait for your eyes to pop out of your head!

Comment: "*use it the C way as long as you keep `#include <stdio.h>`*" - use `#include <cstdio>` instead in C++, and prefix `printf` with `std::`. But you really shouldn't be using C style IO in C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba until the c version crashes due to passing an integer into a character format string, use the safe version until you really need the performance and then you can use printf but make sure you know what you're doing

Comment: @AlanBirtles -- `char` arguments passed to `printf` get promoted to `int` because of the ellipsis, so there's no inherent problem passing an `int` where the format string says character.

Comment: I removed my up vote for this one due to the fact that `int (a)` is strictly C++ cast, and it does not work in C. Tried on several C compilers and it fails. `(int) <variable>` is only C style that I know.